# How to query Apache Druid's __time with milliseconds precision (efficiently)?

Tags: sql, indexing, time, bigdata, druid

This is my `Apache Druid` query that I ran in the Druid’s web GUI:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE __time >= '2023-10-19T09:29:58.613Z'
and __time <= '2023-10-19T09:30:13.613Z'
and my_string_field = 'value'
```

It returns a record where the value in the `__time` field is 2023-10-19T09:29:58.040Z which is less than the lower bound set in my query. The reason seems to be that strings, when parsed to `Druid`'s time format, get truncated to seconds. I think so because the query `SELECT TIME_PARSE('2023-10-19T09:29:58.613Z')` results in `2023-10-19T09:29:58.000Z`. So how do I filter column `__time` precisely up to milliseconds precision (without sacrificing the efficiency of searching by an indexed field)?

Another thing I don't understand is that if I add a field `TIMESTAMP_TO_MILLIS(__time) as tms` to my query it results in `1697794200930` for `__time` that is `2023-10-20T09:30:00.930Z`, and if I add `MILLIS_TO_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP_TO_MILLIS(__time)) as mls` I get back `2023-10-20T09:30:00.930Z`, but when I add `MILLIS_TO_TIMESTAMP(1697794200930) as mls_2` I get `2023-10-20T09:30:00.000Z` instead of `2023-10-20T09:30:00.930Z` (it gets truncated to seconds).

UPDATE:

I found out that the behavior of `MILLIS_TO_TIMESTAMP` was a [bug](https://github.com/apache/druid/issues/13509) and it was fixed in version `25.0.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug and it was fixed. I installed version `27.0.0` locally and `TIME_PARSE` returns milliseconds now and filtering seems to account for milliseconds as well.